# shared hosting and sql server environment security

Tags: sql-server, security, hosting

I was readin this month edition of SQL Server Magazine and in an article about securing Sql Server environment , the author mentioned that developer should try to have the website and the databases run in separate servers for security. I have a shared hosting account and was wondering if it makes sense to buy a second account to move all databases there. Or does it only make sense when using dedicated servers? How would it affect performances on my website?
I use asp.net and have a hosting account with DisountAsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That article probably doesn't apply to your situation. Running the database on a separate server is a measure to protect against root compromise of the web server hosting machine. I a shared hosting environment the same situation would result in compromising *all* accounts on that machine anyway. Depending on the particular settings of your hosting, your account database may alreayd be on a separate server.

Besides, with a shared hosting account is very unlikely you'll even be able to query a database from another account.

Answer (score 1):

If you buy a second server, what will it be, a VPS? I imagine you will get more CPU cycles on a VPS with a dedicated database server than a dedicated machine with multiple databases, but who really knows.

Still, your host isn't running websites on their shared database servers, so what's the difference, security wise?

Performance would me my number one driving factor. I mean if someone compromises your web server, unless your connection strings are encrypted, they've got what they need to connect to the DBs.